# Kendo UI grid - how to display an image in ng-template

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-ui-grid

Essentially we have a images which exists in the `./assets` folder of our web server.

The logic is: display the patient image in the grid if it exists, otherwise render the default image `0.jpg`.

Here's my Kendo UI grid column to show the patient image - IF IT EXISTS:

```
<kendo-grid-column>
  <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>                                  
    <img *ngIf="'./assets/profiles/patients/' + dataItem.PatientID + '.jpg'" src="{{ './assets/profiles/patients/' + dataItem.PatientID + '.jpg'}}" height="40" width="40" style="border-radius:30px;" alt="Patient Image"/>
 </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Here's an idea to combine the logic, render either patient image or the default image:

```html
<kendo-grid-column>
 <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
  <img src="{{ './assets/profiles/patients/' + dataItem.PatientID + '.jpg' ? './assets/profiles/patients/' + dataItem.PatientID + '.jpg' :  defPatientImage}}" 
   height="40" width="40" style="border-radius:30px;" alt="Patient Image"/>
 </ng-template>
 </kendo-grid-column>
```

Problem (in both examples) is that it ALWAYS attempts to display the patient image.

So of course I get console errors something like this :

```
 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/profiles/patients/789456.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

NOTE: I don't have the image path data in my grid data set. For now I have to go straight to the `assets` folder (this is a prototype).

Any idea what's wrong with my `ngIf` statement ?

thanks.

Comment: `'./assets/profiles/patients/' + dataItem.PatientID + '.jpg'` <-- that's a string. A string is truthy unless it's null or empty. Your ternary operator is always evaluating true. So is your *ngIf. This is not an answer because I don't know how to do a filesystem file-exists check from angular. :-/

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. I'll probably need some file utility to check if file exists.

Comment: I mean, in *theory* you could use HttpClient or something and try to do a GET against your own host, but that would be silly so Id only use it as a temporary workaround until I found a more permanent solution (and only do so once in an OnInit or something.)

Comment: so simple I felt so dumb - `onerror=" this.src = './assets/profiles/patients/0.jpg' "`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't realize how simple the solution really was. I just needed the `onerror` event on the `img` tag itself.

```
 <kendo-grid-column>
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
        <img src="{{ './assets/profiles/patients/' + dataItem.PatientID + '.jpg' }}" 
                onerror=" this.src = './assets/profiles/patients/0.jpg' "
                height="40" width="40" style="border-radius:30px;" alt="Patient Image"/>                    
        </ng-template>
 </kendo-grid-column>
```